# Show/hide check boxes on checking a check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a rails form. I have 4 check boxes. What I am trying to do is, hide 3 of the check boxes on page load. And when the 4th check box is checked show the hidden ones. And when the check box is unchecked, again hide the 3 check boxes.

This is what I have so far;

The HTML code generated from the rails form:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td><label for="Question 1">Question 1?</label></td>
    <td><input default="false" id="question1" name="question1" onclick="showOptions()" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>
      <input id="option1" name="option1" type="checkbox" value="idoption1"/>
      <label for="Option 1">Option 1</label>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>
      <input id="option2" name="option2" type="checkbox" value="idoption2"/>
      <label for="Option 2">Option 2</label>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>
      <input id="option3" name="option3" type="checkbox" value="idoption3"/>
      <label for="Option 3">Option 3</label>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the javascript

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

$(document).load(function() {
    $('#option1').hide()
    $('#option2').hide()
    $('#option3').hide()
});

function showOptions() {
    if $('#question1').checked() {
        $('#option1').show()
        $('#option2').show()
        $('#option3').show()
    }
}

< /script>
```

This doesn't work. What is wrong? Thanks

Comment: `$("#question1").change(function(e) { $('#option1, #option2, #option3').toggle(); });`

Comment: or `$("#question1").change(function(e) { if ($(this).is(":checked") { $('#option1, #option2, #option3').show(); } else { $('#option1, #option2, #option3').hide(); }; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the if condition as `if ($('#question1').is(':checked') ){`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Kxsz4/1/)

A better approach is to hide all `checkbox` and it contents using `css` and then add/remove class based on question `checkbox` selection. See below code,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Kxsz4/2/)

**CSS:**

```
.hideContents input, .hideContents label { display: none; }
```

`HTML:` Add class to all those `td's` that has `checkbox` which needs to be hidden.

```
<td class="hideContents">
```

**JS:**

```
$('#question1').on ('change', showOptions);

function showOptions() {
    if ($('#question1').is(':checked') ){
        $('.hideContents')
            .removeClass('hideContents')
            .addClass('showContents');
    } else {
        $('.showContents')
            .removeClass('showContents')
            .addClass('hideContents');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The script end tag should be `</script>` and not `< /script>` this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showOptions() {
    if ($('#question1').checked) {
        $('#option1').show()
        $('#option2').show()
        $('#option3').show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first error is that line is missing parentheses.

```
if $('#question1').checked() {
```

second,

you should append a click or change event to the checkbox.

```
$("#question1").on("click",function(){
    if($(this).checked()){
        $('#option1').show();
        $('#option2').show();
        $('#option3').show();
    }else{
        $('#option1').hide();
        $('#option2').hide();
        $('#option3').hide();
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are doing but  you need to attach event handlers...

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $('#option1').hide()
    $('#option2').hide()
    $('#option3').hide()

    $('#question1').click(function(){ showOptions(); });
});

function showOptions() {
    if ( $('#question1')is(':checked')) {
        $('#option1').show()
        $('#option2').show()
        $('#option3').show()
    }
}
```

You might want a more generic tool to achieve across the board this would involve amending your html a little:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><label for="Question 1">Question 1?</label></td>
  <td><input class="question" default="false" id="question1" name="question1" onclick="showOptions()" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <label><input class="answer" id="option1" name="option1" type="checkbox" value="idoption1"/>Option 1</label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <label><input class="answer" id="option2" name="option2" type="checkbox" value="idoption2"/>Option 2</label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <label><input class="answer" id="option3" name="option3" type="checkbox" value="idoption3"/>Option 3</label>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And some code:

```
$(function(){
    var $answers = $('.answer').parent();
    $answers.hide();

    $("table").on('click',$('input.question'),function(){
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $answers.show();
        }else{
            $answers.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

not tested but reckon thats ok.

IF you have more than one question on a page then pop back and we'll look at restricting it to answers to just the relevant questions.